# google maps tiling scheme index grid

Tags: maps, tilecache, tiling

I have a need to cut tiles from a raster with bounds that result in no partially filled tiles at a particular zoom level (no transparency or black/white areas).  First thought was to overlay an index grid so I could see how to cut the raster.  Is it possible to find shapefile or other description of the tiling grid for google maps or other tiling schemes.

Also interested in other idea for achieving this goal.  One is to simply programmatically discard tiles with empty areas after the fact.    Interested in other suggestions as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page has the information you want http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/ and python script for programatically finding tile bounds.

Comment: well what do you know!